# How IsReminderSet and ReminderDateTime work with Salesforce events

Tags: apex, event

I have an app that creates events in Salesforce for users. It currently does not manually set IsReminderSet to true, but one of the users would like that feature.

I am wondering, how does the IsReminderSet on Salesforce Events integrate with the Activity Reminders settings in My Settings in a Salesforce org?

If I set it to true, and they have it set to set reminder on events to 15 min, will it handle that correctly? Or must I set the ReminderDateTime field of the Event?

Do I set IsReminderSet at all? Or have users go into their settings and change their Activity Reminder settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, in Activity Settings, Enable Reminder

[image: Activity Settings]

Then, at user level, user has to define Activity Reminders under "My Personal Information" menu.

Make sure, no popup blocker is blocking the display of reminder.

[image: Activity Reminders]

Comment: Ok, so org sets Enable activity reminders to checked, then users have to set up their activity reminder settings, then Salesforce will correctly remind them of upcoming events without having to set IsReminderSet or ReminderSetDate to true or some date respectively?

Comment: you are correct, do not need to handle through coding. you can do a small test at your dev, but it works for me

Comment: Alright. They had too many reminder settings all over the place, I didn't know which ones I need to worry about. Thanks for clearing it up!